# Is there a HQL version of Hibernate's Restrictions.sqlRestriction()?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, hibernate-criteria

I have a Java application using Hibernate 4.3.6. We use two different databases (one for regular deploy, other for unit/integration tests). There's a common db-function we'd like to use, but it's called different in each db dialect and Hibernate has no support for it. We've fixed this by simply creating subclasses for each Dialect and using:

```
this.registerFunction("normalizedFunctionName",
   new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER, "arbitraryFunctionName(?1, ?2)"));
```

I can now use `normalizedFunctionName(?, ?)` in HQL. However I'd like to use it when using the Criteria API, something like:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
  .createCriteria(SomeClass.class)
  .add(
     Restrictions.lt("normalizedFunctionName(value, 'bla')", 3)
  );
```

But this doesn't work. Now I've discovered there's:

```
Restrictions.sqlRestriction("arbitraryFunctionName(value, 'bla') < 3");
```

But since that's native SQL and not HQL, I can't use it.

So, my questions are:

- Is there an HQL version of the `Restrictions.sqlRestriction()` feature?
- Or is there another alternative to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: It's 8 months later and I feel I have to add: With Hibernate 5 [the Criteria API has actually been deprecated](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#criteria). Since we're converting all Criteria API usage to HQL for simplicity, this question is no longer relevant for me.